# Записать информацию в лист

Tags: android, list

Информация находится в `response.parsedModel`, я проверял через debuger в нем есть вся информация. Мне нужно записаь ее в лист чтобы передать в адаптер. Вот код.

```
private void showFriends(View v) {
    final VKRequest request = VKApi.friends().get(VKParameters.from(VKApiConst.FIELDS, "first_name, last_name"));
    request.executeWithListener(new VKRequest.VKRequestListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(VKResponse response) {
            super.onComplete(response);
            VKList<VKApiUser> list = (VKList) response.parsedModel;

            playRecyler(list);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Нужен расширенный вопрос, какие данные в какую модель итд

Comment: В VKList нужно передать даные, етим способом что я сделал не получается. Потому что он пустой.

Comment: В каком виде данные внутри `parsedModel` хранятся?

Comment: В VKApiUserFull

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для использования объектов класса `VKApiUserFull` из `VKList'a` вам и нужно явно приводить к `VKList<VKApiUserFull>`, а не к `VKList`.

Замените

```
VKList<VKApiUser> list = (VKList) response.parsedModel;
```

на

```
VKList<VKApiUserFull> list = (VKList<VKApiUserFull>) response.parsedModel;
```