# Не получается вытащить фото человека из VK

Tags: java, android, vkontakte-api

Вытащил список друзей в лист `VKList<VKApiUserFull> list;` , вызываю метод `photo50` - `list.get(position).photo_50`, а там хранится дефолдная картинка vk. Проверил через debug у всех друзей, все картинки дефолдные. Почему так и как правильно это сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В вашем [вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/645199/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D0%B2-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82) вы показали код-обращение к `vk-api`:

```
final VKRequest request = VKApi.friends().get(VKParameters.from(VKApiConst.FIELDS, 
"first_name, last_name"));
```

Обратите внимание на то, что вы запрашиваете. В этом конкретном случае выделаете запрос на получение `"first_name"` и `"last_name"`. Все остальные поля в модели заполняются дефолтными значениями уже у вас на устройстве. Для получения фотографий добавьте в массив полей одноимённый параметр `"photo_50"`. Полный список доступных полей можно найти [здесь](https://vk.com/dev/objects/user) и [здесь](https://vk.com/dev/objects/user_2).

Answer (score 2):

в параметрах запроса нужно добавить поля которые нужно вернуть:

```
VKRequest vkRequest = VKApi.friends().get(VKParameters.from(VKApiConst.FIELDS,"photo_50"));
```

а так ка вы не запрашиваете  `photo_50` то возвращает дефолтную вк картинку